# Guice + Jersey integration injects null objects

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven-3, guice, jersey-2.0

Following the excellent step-by-step given in [Up and running on AppEngine with Maven, Jersey and Guice - Part 3](http://akshayrangnekar.github.io/blog/2014/03/18/up-and-running-on-appengine-with-maven-jersey-and-guice-part-3/), I have been able to get everything working except injecting objects into a Jersey POJO.

The only difference I have from that configuration is that I also have Objectify integrated, but that is working.

The `TestClass` instance (a singleton) injected into `HelloWorldServlet` works, but the `TestClass` and `SecondTest` (`RequestScoped`) objects injected into the `HeyResource` POJO are always `null`.

I suspect the the interaction between HK2 and Guice is to blame here, but this is my first project with Guice *and* Jersey *and* HK2, so I am all at sea.

My configuration is:

- Platform: Win 7
- GAE SDK 1.9.26
- Jave 1.7.0_79
- Jersey: 2.5.1
- Guice: 4.0
- Objectify: 5.1.7
- HK2 Guice-bridge: 2.2.0
- Maven 3.3.3

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough information here to give an answer.  Could you provide your code snippets?

Answer (score 6):

With Jersey 2 you don't need to use the Guice web wrapper like was needed with Jersey 1. You already have the `guice-bridge`, you just need to configure it with HK2 within the Jersey configuration. See [The Guice/HK2 Bridge](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/guice-bridge.html).

You basically need to get a handle on the HK2's `ServiceLocator` to bind the two frameworks. Jersey allows you to inject the locator in many locations of the application. The place where you would need it most is in the configuration class (i.e. the `ResourceConfig`). Here is an example of how you can configure it.

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public JerseyConfig(ServiceLocator locator) {
        packages("your.packages.to.scan");

        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(locator);
        // add your Guice modules.
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule());
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = locator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
    }
}
```

If you are using web.xml to configure the app, you can add this class to your configuration with an init-param

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.stackoverflow.jersey.JerseyConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: The link to "The Guice/HK2 Bridge" is broken, but I think this has the information: https://javaee.github.io/hk2/guice-bridge.html