# Guice 4.0 Jersey 2.22.1 - ServiceLocatorImpl has been shut down

Tags: java, maven, guice, jersey-2.0

I am trying to get a Jersey 2 web app running with Guice 4 for dependency injection and Maven. I also use https://github.com/Squarespace/jersey2-guice.

The WAR-file builds fine, but when trying to deploy it on a Jetty web server I get the following stack trace:

```
[2016-01-09 09:13:24,581] Artifact packageapi:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
2016-01-09 21:13:49.760:WARN:/.0-SNAPSHOT:Scanner-1: unavailable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServiceLocatorImpl(GuiceServiceLocator-1,0,1115440386) has been shut down
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.checkState(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2270)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:737)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:714)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:330)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2016-01-09 21:13:49.761:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Scanner-1: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5066ebe1{/package-1.0-SNAPSHOT,file:///home/my/Dropbox/Programming/Java/packageapi/target/package-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,STARTING}{/home/my/Dropbox/Programming/Java/packageapi/target/package-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war}
javax.servlet.ServletException: Jersey Web Application@ef2c8cb4==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer,1,false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServiceLocatorImpl(GuiceServiceLocator-1,0,1115440386) has been shut down
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.checkState(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2270)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:737)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:714)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities.enablePerThreadScope(ServiceLocatorUtilities.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:330)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>package</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>package</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squarespace.jersey2-guice</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey2-guice</artifactId>
            <version>0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.package.guice.ApiServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is the JerseyGuiceServletContextListener:

```
package my.package.guice;

import com.google.inject.Module;
import com.squarespace.jersey2.guice.JerseyGuiceServletContextListener;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ApiServletContextListener extends JerseyGuiceServletContextListener {
    private static final ApiModule apiModule = new ApiModule();
    @Override
    protected List<? extends Module> modules() {
        return Collections.singletonList(apiModule);
    }
}
```

The test resource:

```
package my.package;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @Inject
    @Named("test")
    private String s;

    public TestResource() {
        System.out.println("LOLOLOLOL");
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        System.out.println("LOLOLOL");
        return s;
    }
}
```

The GuiceModule:

```
package my.package.guice;

import my.package.TestResource;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;

public class ApiModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(TestResource.class);

        bind(String.class)
                .annotatedWith(Names.named("test"))
                .toInstance("It works!");
    }
}
```

Switching to Guice 3.0 does not solve the issue.
How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably don't need the jersey2-guice. Try to get rid of any reference to it, and try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32610442/2587435)